# 2 jQuery scripts not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jQuery 2.0.3 and bootstrap.

I have function created in jquery, one for the dropdown menu and other for changing images on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Display radom image on page refresh
    var images = [];
    images = ['banner1.jpg', 'banner2.jpg', 'banner3.jpg', 'banner4.jpg', 'banner5.jpg', 'banner6.jpg'];
    $('<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/inner-page-slider/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('#sliderImgInnerWrap');
});

$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});​
```

When both of the are used together, the function for images on page load stops working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is your last chunk of code outside the doc ready?

Comment: I think it's because you're stopping the propagation, use `preventDefault` instead

Comment: as @j08691 implies, move the `.click` function into the `.ready` function

Comment: @j08691 even if i put the last chunk of code inside the doc ready still it stops working...

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that my comment was a solution; I was curious why you did that. Also, are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Error in the console is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score -1):

try using non-conflict....

use jQuery instead of $

If not that have a look at any errors on the console.